# Good hash for a set of numbers and a special number?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, hash

I have arrays of integers such as

```
[1, 3, 5], 
[7, 2, 10],
[50, 12, 10],
[20, 1, 34],
```

I'm trying to make a hashing algorithm that given one of these arrays will return a unique hash for each so that I can quickly look if they exist in the HashMap.

The hash should be the same if both arrays contain the same set of numbers and the last number in the array is the same.

For example

```
// these are the same because they contain the same numbers and have same last number (5)
Hash([3, 1, 5]) -> 5678326 
Hash([1, 3, 5]) -> 5678326

// different hash because the last number in the array is different
Hash([5, 1, 3]) -> 9877124

// different hash because different set of values
Hash([7, 1, 5]) -> 2123466
```

The values in the arrays are in the rage 0 - 100 and they are all unique (so there can be no duplicates in the array) and the maximum size of the array is 100.

What would be a really good hashing algorithm for this?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be specific to the Java language. Also, what have you tried doing so far?

Comment: Ok so combine the first two with a commutative function (so their order doesn't matter) and then combine that with the last one however you want.

Comment: What you're describing the need for is a hash code. Hash codes don't have to be guaranteed unique--just unlikely to produce a collision.

Comment: I tried variations of basically multiplying all numbers, then dividing by squareroot of last number or something like that, just need something with minimum collisions so that my code isn't slow

Comment: Well don't do that, if you use square roots and division it will be ridiculously slow which is the opposite of what you want from a hash function.

Comment: Apache's [HashCodeBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) states that `It follows the rules laid out in the book Effective Java by Joshua Bloch`.

Comment: @KevinMeredith I see no obvious way there to append items without order, besides just summing them first or something like that, perhaps I missed something

Comment: @UnholySheep yeah my bad I'm just overriding the hashCode function in java to write this.

Comment: If you're doing this to use your values as keys in the JDK's `HashMap`, the hashcode will be useless unless you also implement `equals()` along the same lines.

Comment: From the question it sounds like you're using the wrong data structure to store your values. Why not create a class containing a `Set<Integer>` (or a [`Multiset<Integer>`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html)) and a separate `int` and implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` normally?

Answer (score 3):

Compute hash code for the input as if it was a set, multiply by a prime, and add hash code of last element.

Along the lines of

```
new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(input)).hashCode() * 31 + input[input.length - 1]
```

but for performance you'd probably want to do it manually by adding the input items up in a loop instead of creating a `HashSet`.

Note that this won't *"return a unique hash for each [input]"* as you request - you'd need [perfect hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) for that which would probably be quite overkill.

Comment: You can't use `Arrays.asList()` if `input` is `int[]`.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is a weird setup, but one way to implement it is with a custom Object:

```
public class YourCustomObject {
    private final int[] allButLast;
    private final int last;

    public YourCustomObject(int[] value){
        this.value = value;
        this.allButLast = Arrays.copyOfRange(value, 0, value.length-1);
        Arrays.sort(allButLast);
        this.last = value[value.length-1];
    }
    private final int[] value;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }else if (( o instanceof YourCustomObject)) {
            YourCustomObject that = (YourCustomObject) o;
            return last == that.last && Arrays.equals(allButLast, that.allButLast);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(allButLast, last);
    }

    public int[] getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

This object's equals/hashCode properties rely on the same array elements in any order, excluding the last element, which must be the same. You can use this object as a key in a HashMap, and it will work as specified.

Also, since arrays are mutable, I'd probably make a defensive copy in both the constructor and the getter.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most optimized solution, but it should do what you want:

```
int hash(int[] array) {
    array = array.clone();
    Arrays.sort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
    return Arrays.hashCode(array);
}
```

Another option is to add elements to a set and call `Objects.hash(set, array[array.length - 1])`.

Answer (score -2):

If you just need to produce a hash for the purpose of storing the arrays in the buckets of a Map or Set, you don't need to create your own hashing function. The one in `java.util.Arrays` will do. They were designed specifically for this purpose.

Additionally, hash codes don't have to be guaranteed unique--just unlikely to produce a collision. In fact, guaranteeing they're unique would slow down the Map much more than the occasional  collision would.

No need to reinvent the wheel--just use `java,util.Arrays.hashCode` to compute the hash code for your arrays.

Comment: No. This would not be consistent with the equals method.

Comment: @Henry: equal objects must produce the same hash code. The other way around is not guaranteed.

Comment: Exactly, now [3, 1, 5] and [1, 3, 5] are equal as I understand it, yet they would have probably different hash codes.

Comment: @Henry: probably? Why not try `Arrays.equals` and `Arrays.hashCode` and see if they produce inconsistent results? Since that would be a pretty major bug in java core i don't think that's likely. This usage is exactly what that utility function is for.

Comment: I don't talk about `Arrays.equals` but about the equal semantics the OP wants to have.

Comment: @Henry: He's talking about putting these objects in a Map. The semantics required by Maps are exactly the semantics these methods provide--by design.

Comment: @Henry: Maybe read my answer again--particularly the first two sentences.

Comment: @Henry: ...and if you read the documentation, the example you give in your second comment is by definition NOT equal.

Comment: They by definition must be equal, that's what OP wants. The documentation doesn't even enter that discussion.

Comment: @harold: The point is **it does not matter** for the stated purpose of storing objects in a Map or a Set.

Comment: Presumably he's replacing the definition of `equals` as well, otherwise his whole question is moot.

Comment: @harold ...so your objection is that this may not solve a problem that the OP didn't ask for a solution to? Instead it just solves the problem he asked for a solution to?

Comment: @harold Just to be clear, I understand that this doesn't satisfy his criteria for equality. My point is that that criteria is not necessary for his greater stated purpose of storing objects in a Map efficiently.

Comment: Ok right, but that is not a complete description of what OP stated as the purpose. For some other reason that OP did not explain, swapping the first two elements must count as the same key again. That wouldn't do anything for efficiency so I'm assuming it's for semantics.

Comment: @harold: I agree, and I made it very clear with my first two sentences that this solution differs from the implementation he's asking for but is a better way to solve the actual problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127329/discussion-between-harold-and-alvin-thompson).

Comment: @harold: This is getting ridiculous. Now you're claiming that the functions placed in java core specifically for the OP's stated purpose are not adequate for that purpose? If that were true, you should be filing a bug with Oracle and not telling the poster write his own version.